# ASP.net Pop up Alert without page load

Tags: asp.net, popup

In ASP.NET -->

I want to popup an alert window in the case of an event. I don't have a button, i do not load the page at that event. When I searched i got a lot of java script examples but I can't use them as they work either on a button click or on page load. I just want a pop window to come as soon as I capture a particular event. I keep checking for the events every 5 second, as soon as i capture one event, there is a switch case for the actions to follow according to the event captured. For one particular case, i need one pop up "Sorry" along with an OK button. Can someone tell me what to do.

Thanks

Comment: How do you capture the event? Pls elaborate by giving a code example.

Comment: When you write about an event, you don't mean an .NET Event (as in delegate etc.), do you? I was a bit irritated by the mention that you check it every 5 seconds. What do you check every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) which is part of the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/(S(fu2l2uzphr2u3u45q2dnez55))/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/). I have used it many times to display messages, as it's much nicer than a javascript alert. If your event is captured in javascript, you can simply display it. If your event is captured in the ASP.NET code-behind, you can either display it via a page refresh, or you can put it into an [UpdatePanel](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel.aspx) and trigger that, which will cause it to appear without your page refreshing.

Comment: You could also use the Timer Control to update the panel at intervals - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb398865.aspx